# Daily Rebbe Video

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, chabad, chassidic-rebbe

I'm looking for a place where I can sign up and receive a daily video of the Lubavitcher Rebbe through my e-mail. Could someone point me to a place where I can do this?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/dailyrebbevideo/

Comment: @Ploni - Great, but I don't use Facebook. I asked for an e-mail sign up.

Comment: Jews not Judaism?

Comment: That's a really specific request. Is there a reason you (a) think such a service may exist, and/or (b) want such a service, in particular? If so, please [edit] it in. (E.g. "I know there's [this service on FB](https://www.facebook.com/dailyrebbevideo/), but I don't use FB, and I feel that daily video of RMM"S would be useful for ...") @DonielF, I think it's fair to assume that this is looking for video of *Torah* from RMM"S, which is 100% on-topic.

Comment: @IsaacMoses If that's what he wrote in the OP I would 100% agree with you. As it stands, I can't tell whether that's what he wants or whether he wants videos of his apple bobbing. (Note that my close vote is only 1/4.) If he were to edit that in, I would absolutely retract my close vote.

Comment: @DonielF, sorry, but I don't think that your stated uncertainty is consistent with a reasonable reading of this post by anyone who is familiar with contemporary Judaism, reading this post on a Judaism site. No one is ever, ever going to post an answer to this question with videos of RMM"S bobbing for apples or doing anything other than teaching Torah. There's no value at all to expecting that someone might and then trying to exclude this question on that basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to [this website](https://mymaor.org/kids/), and scroll down till you see "Via Email". Enter your email, and first & last name and click "subscribe". There is also an option there to subscribe via whatsapp.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHSnlLKaXqJADnyFpcgUxVA

This link should take you to the JewishMedia site via You Tube. They are part of Jewish Educational Media, the multi-media arm of Chabad.

If you subscribe to their feed, they will send you email notifications for their almost daily uploads.

If you would like more information about JEM and their activities, this link might be of interest.

http://home.jemedia.org/default.asp